# Codingbat recursion to while loop?

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

I know that the recursion series has "DO NOT USE LOOPS" written all over it, but I decided to practice those with loops anyway. I am working on the strDist() one, but I can't seem to get it completely.

The problem:

Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length.

```
strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9
strDist("catcowcat", "cow") → 3
strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") → 9
```

My code:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = str.length() - 1;
    int index = 0;
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    while (index < str.length()) {
        if (str.substring(index, index + sub.length()).equals(sub)) {
            min = index;
            index = str.length();
        }
        index++;
    }
    index = str.length() - 1;
    while (index >= 0) {
        if (str.substring(index - sub.length(), index).equals(sub)) {
            max = index;
            index = 0;
        }
        index--;
    }
    return max - min;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some reason you **must** reinvent the wheel, use [`String.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) and [`String.lastIndexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-) like

```
public static int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    if (str.contains(sub)) {
        return sub.length() + str.lastIndexOf(sub) - str.indexOf(sub);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Codebender Oops. Thanks. I removed temp variables without re-testing. That was silly.

Comment: It doesn't really fit the criteria of resolving the recursion excercise with loops.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
 public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  if(!str.contains(sub)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if(str.startsWith(sub) && str.endsWith(sub)) {
    return str.length();
  }
  return strDist(str.substring(str.indexOf(sub),str.lastIndexOf(sub)+sub.length()),sub);
}
```